# How to send data from Node js server to client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I currently set up a node server which gets some data submitted from a html page and uses it to fetch data from an API. now I would like to display this data in a graphic format to a new html page (or even the same if possible).
In order to do this I think I should first send the data to the client side js. So that it gets the data to create the graph onto the new html page. But how would I do this? I tried to look for some examples unsuccessfully.

Here's a failing attempt at this (I omitted some code that I think wasn't influencial):

//server (Node JS)

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded( {extended: true} ));
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
let values;

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
});

async function fillArrays (from, to) {
    ...
}

const fetchData = async () => {
    ...

    values = ...;
}

app.post('/input', async function(req,res){

    await fillArrays(req.body.a, req.body.b);

    console.log("End");
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/graph.html'));
    res.json(await fetchData());

});



app.listen(port);
console.log('Server started at http://localhost:' + port);
```

graph.html:

```
<head>
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.14.0.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="chart.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='myDiv'></div>
</body>
```

chart.js :

```
let dataset;
//attempt at getting data from server side
const promise = fetch('/input');

promise.then(response => {
    if(!response.ok){
        console.error(response)
    } else {
        return console.log(response);
    }
}).then(result => {
    dataset = result;
})

let range1 = Math.min(dataset[0]);
let range2 = Math.max(dataset[0]);
        
var trace = {
               ...
            }
                
var data = trace;
                
var layout = {
                ...
            };

                
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

Comment: Are all the requests failing or just the post request? because there's only a `return` from the post requst, not `res.send()`

Comment: @Cevil only the get request won't work. The post request works fine. You're suggesting I should use res.send instead of return?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Sorry I meant to say that the server fetches the data from the API based on inputs given from the client (a HTML form). fetchData works fine. It fetches the data and saves it in the values array as it should

Comment: Do not store the data in a global variable (this will not work if you have concurrent requests). Instead, have the `app.post('/input', ...)` middleware use the data for respond to the client, e.g., `res.json(await fetchData())`.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen After following your advice (I'll update the code above) I can finally see the data in json format on local:8080/input. However how can I use this data in client side js to create the graph?

Comment: See, for example, https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start